# cannot print pointer to element of unordered_map

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

I've installed CodeBloks and I was testing it with a simple problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    mp[1]=2;
    mp[2]=3;
    for(unordered_map<int,int>::iterator it = mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

Comment: That's not the error message [that you get](https://ideone.com/Fc4Dc1): "_error: no match for ‘`operator<<`' (operand types are ‘`std::ostream` {aka `std::basic_ostream<char>`}’ and ‘`std::pair<const int, int>`’_" And, `std::pair` does not have such operator overloaded.

Comment: When reading error messages start at the top, not the bottom. Especially for errors like this where there is *a lot* of output for one error.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

```
for( const auto& n : u ) {
    std::cout << "Key:[" << n.first << "] Value:[" << n.second << "]\n";
}
```

A map (unordered or not) is composed of a `key`, and a `value`. You can access it with `first` and `second` from the iterator.

Comment: Thank you so much ,I am now sorry to have bothered you with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The error may be misleading. The actual problem is that unordered map iterates in pairs of keys and values, and there is no `<<` operator for printing these pairs directly.

You can access the key through `it->first` and the value through `it->second`:

```
for(unordered_map<int,int>::iterator it = mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++)
    cout<<it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/O9DiiI)

Answer (score 0):

A map stores key/value-pairs, and `it` provides a member `first` (standing for the key) and a member `second` (standing for the value). Try the following `cout...`-statement:

```
cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Structured bindings would work nicely for this:

```
for(auto [first, second] : mp) {
    cout << first << '\t' << second << '\n';
}
```